# Alter Ajax callback on Webforms

Tags: 8, ajax, webforms

I'm loading a webform on a Ajax modal dialog. The form submission is also set to Ajax. I want to alter the Ajax submit callback so I can have more control over the form behaviour. I'm not being able to do that. The callback being executed is always submitAjaxForm, set on the WebformAjaxFormTrait trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  ....
  if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => '/path/to/your/controller/or/webformhandler/submitModalFormAjax',
      'event' => 'click',
    ];
}
```

in your *.module and then implement the callback function somewhere

```
public static function submitModalFormAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {...}
```

Comment: I've found out hook_webform_submission_form_alter will work as well.